# Вывод данных из базы в html

Tags: php, html

Каким образом можно сделать вывод данных из базы в файле html? То есть первым загружается index.html и в нем таблица с данными из БД

**Обновление**
Спасибо, сделаю так.

Comment: Есть возможность назначить файлу html в качестве обработчика интерпретатор PHP, например, средствами Apache?

Comment: Нет, результат будет отдаваться, никаких манипуляций с сервером не должно быть

Comment: Если вам подошел один из вариантов ответа, нужно поставить напротив него флажок. это покажет остальным пользователем, что вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPD: исправился, не сразу понял вопрос.

Создавать этот html средствами php:

```
http://site/index.php?html=page1
```

А чтобы для посетителя это выглядело, как страница html, прописать в `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php?html=$1 [nc]
```

И тогда при открытии `http://site/page1.html` он будет переадресован на `http://site/index.php?html=page1`

Answer (score 0):

> Каким образом можно сделать вывод данных из базы в файле html?

в настройках apache сервера
задать html как разрешение файлов обрабатываемых php

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .html
```

также можно это сделать с помощью файла .htaccess, Добавьте или отредактируйте существующую строку вида:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php4 .html
```